# Postback after selecting a value from a dropdown jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

After I select a value from a combobox in the page, it does not return on the server side.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dllTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dllTest_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

I am making the dropdownlist to a combobox

```
$("#<%=dllTest.ClientID%>").combobox();
```

Also I want to trigger the ddlTest_SelectedIndexChange.

I tried doing this `$('#dllTest').combobox();` and adding a property of the dropdown to `ClientIDMode="Static"` not working.

What I want is after I select a value from the combobox, the selectedindexchange will fire in code behind

Comment: Do you get any javascript error ?

Comment: No. its not a broken build

Comment: Are you making sure you wrap that in the `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `$(document).ready($(function () {
            $('#<%= dllTest.ClientID %>').combobox();
        }));`
I coded it like this.

Comment: Do you do anything with the DropDownList on PageLoad? If so, is that code wrapped in `if(!Page.IsPostback)`?

Comment: I am populating the dropdown from codebehind and getting the values from db. and calling it inside the `if(!Page.IsPostback)`

Comment: I assume you are using this library: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combobox.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use select function of combo-box as as follows. Because when you use combo box it hide you drop-down list.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
                 ui.item.option.selected = true;
                self._trigger("selected", event, {
                     item: ui.item.option
                 }
                 );
                 __doPostBack('<%= dllTest.UniqueID %>', '');
             },
```